# OutOfMemoryException when declaring an array of 100mln floats

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, out-of-memory

For some reason I'm getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException` when I try to declare a new array of float of size 100000000. It's supposed to take up 381MB and my PC has 8GB (2.5 of which are taken up by Windows and other apps).

```
float[] kineticTile = new float[dimsize]; //<- exception thrown here (dimsize is 100000000)
```

Declaring same kind of array in other parts of my application works fine.

Other posts on SO have explanations of the problem but I still cannot see an actual solution to it.

I do image rendering and processing and need the whole image in memory (I copy it from a CUDA card) so cannot cut it into smaller fragments.
I thought with 8GB of RAM these mere 380MB should not be a problem

Comment: ok, it explains what might be the cause but i don't see an actual solution there

Comment: this could have something to do with float being a primitive type and thus being stored in the stack rather than the heap. See [difference between stack and heap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/80113/937093). Why do you want such a large array?

Comment: I do image rendering and processing and need the whole image in memory (I copy it from a CUDA card). I thought with 8GB of RAM these mere 380MB should not be a problem

Comment: Have a look at Shift Technology's and Trisped's answers in the duplicate thread.  You can try building as x64 and see if that works.  Otherwise, Trisped had a code example of an alternative way to structure that which may also do the trick.  Do either of those work for you?

Comment: OK, switching Platform target to x64 did the trick! Thx!